# Java How to i get the name of the object from a mouseEvent

Tags: java, swing

i'd like to get the name of the JLabel on MouseReleased event.
So, i have this JLabel array of 100 labels, and i want to get back their name,
so i can modify my Boolean array of 100 booleans.
maybe if you are familiar with the 1010game i have to create that.
put it in simply i want to get the name of the JPanel in the MouseReleased event.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class needsrefactor extends JFrame {
    JFrame Window;
    JPanel a, b;
    SouthFrame sf = new SouthFrame();
    final public JLabel[] GamePlace;
    GridLayout lay;
    MouseListener m1;
    Boolean[] BackEnd;
    MouseAdapter lis;
    LabelAdapter lb = new LabelAdapter();

    public needsrefactor() {
        BackEnd = new Boolean[100];
        b = new JPanel();
        b.setOpaque(true);
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
        b.setVisible(true);
        // EVENTES
        m1 = new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                JComponent JC = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                TransferHandler TH = JC.getTransferHandler();
                TH.exportAsDrag(JC, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
                System.out.println("Foo");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.getID());
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        };
        Window = new JFrame();
        Window.doLayout();
        Window.setVisible(true);
        Window.setSize(800, 1000);
        Window.setResizable(false);
        // Window.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // lay = new GridLayout(10,10);
        GamePlace = new JLabel[100];
        a = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10, 1, 1));
        a.setSize(799, 500);
        // a = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(10));
        a.setBackground(Color.white);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            BackEnd[i] = false;
            this.GamePlace[i] = new JLabel("Label");
            this.GamePlace[i].setOpaque(true);
            this.GamePlace[i].setBackground(Color.black);
            this.GamePlace[i].setVisible(true);
            // this.GamePlace[i].setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
            // this.GamePlace[i].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(15, 15));
            this.a.add(GamePlace[i]);
            this.GamePlace[i].addMouseListener(m1);
            this.GamePlace[i].setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
            this.GamePlace[i].setName(Integer.toString(i));
            /*
             * this.GamePlace[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
             * 
             * @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
             * System.out.println(JLabel.getName()); } });
             */
        }
        // this.a.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,300));
        // this.GamePlace[1].setIcon(new
        // ImageIcon(needsrefactor.class.getResource("/sources/picture.png")));
        // a.setBounds(1, 1, 800, 600);
        Window.add(a, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // b=new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,5));
        // b.setSize(800, 299);
        // Window.add(b,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        sf.setOpaque(true);
        sf.setBackground(Color.green);
        sf.setVisible(true);
        sf.setBounds(WIDTH, WIDTH, 799, 300);
        // Window.add(sf,BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        Window.add(sf.SouthFrame, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

SouthFrame:
http://pastebin.com/J29RtZgh

Comment: `((JLabel)event.getSource()).getName()`

Comment: Question: 1) what is a JLabel's "name"? 2) Do you want to get the index of the JLabel in your array? If so, simply use the MouseEvent's `getSource()` method to get the pressed/released JLabel and iterate through your array to see which label matches the source. 3) Try to post small program code that we can run, a [mcve]. 4) Please avoid obscenities in your post. Kids read this site.

Comment: oh, that "LabelAdapter lb = new LabelAdapter();" has accidently been left in the code

Comment: And I suppose the SouthFrame was also accidentally left in the code as well?

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Edit: obscenity removed from code

Comment: nono southframe is part of the window, that's intentional, that's another class, but irrelevent to the question so i thought that it wasn't necesseary to implement it to the question. btw thank you very much i think this will help... at the moment when my netbeans will accept my main method as it is...

Comment: i'm beginner, so by iterate it thorough you mean compare them to each other?

Comment: `"that's another class, but irrelevent to the question ..."` -- hardly irrelevant as its presence makes your code non-compilable and non-runnable for us. Again, please read the [mcve] protocol. As for iteration, use a for loop to iterate through the components you're comparing, and inside the loop compare an array item with the source component.

Comment: i'll read those and memorise it, i promise but i need to make this work by monday.... addid SouthFrame in Pastebin i dont know if it's appropiate or should have just copy-pasted it in here

Comment: I'll wait for your [mcve] that you post here -- a smallest compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem for us. Please comment back using `@hovercraft` so I'll know you've posted it.

Comment: Also note that if you're in a hurry, posting a decent mcve offers your best chance of getting quick decent help. Also note that you shouldn't post code in links to off-site repositories.

Comment: well, i'll do and also i want to give you a big thank you cos i made it work with your help, now i just want to figure out how to make it while drag'n drop, but nevertheless, i got what i wanted, thanks!